# What's the pinout for Fujitsu 16-pin PSUs? ( eg. model D12-250P1A )

Tags: power-supply

The Fujitsu ESPRIMO P420 E85+ desktop PC ( and probably various other Fujitsu models ) uses an apparently proprietary PSU with a 16-pin Molex connector. The PSU is described in Fujitsu's sparse documentation as "12V-only". The motherboard is described as 'D3230'.

Lacking a replacement, in theory, a standard ATX PSU could be hacked up to work in a pinch, but... what's the pinout for the 16-pin PSU?

Bonus question: Is there a standard emerging for 12V-only pinouts?

Comment: Do you have a picture? Judging by Google Image search results, the pinout is fairly obvious. Yellow for +12V, black for neutral, green for on-signal, just like any other PSU.

Comment: If you are not adding peripherals, like internal drives or a high-end graphics card, just order a similar/compatible PSU online (it's compatible with S26113-E611-V70 and  S26113-E611-V70-01) or contact a Fujitsu service center nearest to you -- Fujitsu promised parts availability up to 5 years after end of product life for the ESPRIMO P420 E85+, so they must have a compatible PSU in stock.

Answer (score -1):

**Works with a Dell Micro-ATX power supply.**

Spent a fair few hours tearing away at pc chassis that in no way fits but 2 and half hours of tin opening later i have a pic case that looks like a flattened pizza box shnazzzy stuff it is but to the point.Its a very tricky motherboard to get running, i got lucky with the pin selection when i was all but ready to give up, I started ramming it in all the diff holes in desperation like a true romantic eventually came on what seems to be a sweetspot.

Next to the motherboard power molex, there( i) have a set of coloured pins. Lovely. there are 3 yellow pins, two of the are covered by a jumper. The third yellow pin is exposed, place another jumper across that third pin and pair it with the pin that sits directly next to it along the linear flow, its a different colour orange i think, but basically short the last yellow pin that sits exposed with the pin adjacent (linear).

This pin config sets the motherboard in Bios recovery mode. Pull the power cable out of the power supply and return every 5 or so seconds, eventually it will light up on its own.

---

*p.s. First life came from the power supply self test button on the Dell PSU.

*It showed green and the machine began to boot so i knew it was good to go but took another hours getting it to come on and stay on by usual means. I had screwy wedged against the psu test button for the most part. Trick seems to be in the AC power On/Off tingymibob but i didn't get round to removing battery bios come to think of it :D~  (some 4+ hours later.. it comes to mind *picks nose*).**